# How to add custom data-theme swatches without overriding the deafault ones?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using Themeroller I can make my own color theme to be used instead of the default one. But I want to add a couple of data-theme swatches (e.g. "f" and "g") and use them with the default ones. Can I do it with the Themeroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [jquery mobile's css file](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css) , you'd see a structure like this :

```
/* Swatches */
/* A ---------------------------------------------*/

.ui-bar-a {
    border: 1px solid       #333 /*{a-bar-border}*/;
    background:             #111 /*{a-bar-background-color}*/;
    color:                  #fff /*{a-bar-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bar-shadow-x}*/ -1px /*{a-bar-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bar-shadow-radius}*/ #000 /*{a-bar-shadow-color}*/;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #3c3c3c /*{a-bar-background-start}*/), to( #111 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #111 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #111 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #111 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #3c3c3c /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #111 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #3c3c3c /*{a-bar-background-start}*/, #111 /*{a-bar-background-end}*/);
}
.ui-bar-a,
.ui-bar-a input,
.ui-bar-a select,
.ui-bar-a textarea,
.ui-bar-a button {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif /*{global-font-family}*/;
}
.ui-bar-a .ui-link-inherit {
    color: #fff /*{a-bar-color}*/;
}
.ui-bar-a a.ui-link {
    color: #7cc4e7 /*{a-bar-link-color}*/;
    font-weight: bold;
}
...
/* B -----------------------------------------*/
...
/* C -----------------------------------------*/
...
/* D -----------------------------------------*/
...
/* E -----------------------------------------*/
...

/* Structure */
/* links within "buttons" -----------------------*/
```

You could add theme "f" (or whatever you want to name it) before `/* Structure */`, or in a separate CSS file referenced **after** jQM's css. This will not affect the previous styles. But be sure to name the elements this way :

```
.ui-bar-themename
```

Else, you'll over ride the existing styles.

Answer (score 1):

In Themeroller I added additional styles for letters F and G and tuned them as I needed (A - E were left untouched). Then I downloaded the zip file with styles, copied the `/* F` and `/* G` sections (thanks to @hungerpain), put them in a separate .css and linked it after the jQM .css.

Comment: If you think this is the right answer, pls mark it as the right answer, or my answer as the right one

Answer (score 0):

All jquery mobile themes executed by  jquery-mobile.js  files. In .js files defined only 5 themes. A and B and C and D and E. 
if you want to add your custom theme for example "F"  in to this group themes, you should add this themes id in to  jquery-mobile.js  for executing. do you undrestand?
In simple case you can made your custom theme by chenging in for example "A"  or "B" themes parameters.